# SyntaxError: 'yield' outside of function in Python

Tags: python, yield

I've read numerous posts on this, and I realise lots of people have asked this, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to draw a grid with coordinates for a project I'm working on, and I was trying some code for generating it. I tryed this one, but I keep getting that error. What's wrong with the code? I've tryed different indentations but it doesn't work.

```
stepsize = 0.001

for x in range(0, 10, stepsize):
  for y in range(0, 10, stepsize):
    yield (x,y)
```

[How can I generate a regular geographic grid using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342355/how-can-i-generate-a-regular-geographic-grid-using-python)

^^The original q+a

Thanks to everyone who helped, I'm not sure why that code was posted considering it wouldn't work anyway! Sorry for my misunderstanding, I haven't used generators before. :)

Comment: `yield` must be used inside a function. Your for loops are not inside a function.

Comment: "but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong." The error is telling you exactly - you have `yield` outside of a function definition, which doesn't make any sense. What do you *expect* `yield (x, y)` to do here?

Comment: add a def functionName: at above your code sample. indent.

Comment: Besides all the comments, don't think you can use `float` stepsize as  incremental `step`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yield` keyword is used to "return" a generator object from a function

[Stack Overflow Question on the yield keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

It cannot be used outside a function, like in your code.

If this was under a `def` statement, then it would be fine, however there is no `def` statement here, so it raises an error

---

Also, not in relation to the question, but these lines won't work:

```py
for x in range(0, 10, stepsize):
  for y in range(0, 10, stepsize):
```

because `stepsize` is a float, and the `range` function only handles integers - it will say something like `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 0):

To add to what was already said, you could implement your code by composing generators to produce the required output.

```
def increment(start, end, delta):
    while start < end:
        yield start
        start += delta

def double_increment(start, end, delta):
    for x in increment(start, end, delta):
        for y in increment(start, end, delta):
            yield x, y
```

Example:

```
for x, y in double_increment(0, 1, 0.4):
    print(f"{x:.2f} {y:.2f}")
```

```
0.00 0.00
0.00 0.40
0.00 0.80
0.40 0.00
0.40 0.40
0.40 0.80
0.80 0.00
0.80 0.40
0.80 0.80
```

You could also use `product` to produce the double increment:

```
from itertools import product
for x, y in product(increment(0, 1, 0.4), repeat=2):
    print(f"{x:.2f} {y:.2f}")
```

Combining more itertools you could do:

```
from itertools import product, count, takewhile
for x, y in product(takewhile(lambda x: x < 1, count(0, step=0.4)), repeat=2):
    print(f"{x:.2f} {y:.2f}")
```